# CF network error in iOS 16.1.1 with XCode 14.1 unable to find a solution

Tags: ios, xcode

error log in xcode , no issue in iOS version below 16 , im using XCode 14.1

```
libsp.dylib`spd_checkin_socket.cold.1:
    0x204699364 <+0>:  adrp   x8, 143811
    0x204699368 <+4>:  adrp   x9, 0
    0x20469936c <+8>:  add    x9, x9, #0xa3f; "Linked against modern SDK, VOIP socket will not wake. Use Local Push Connectivity instead"
    0x204699370 <+12>: str    x9, [x8, #0x130]
->  0x204699374 <+16>: brk    #0x1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the POD file and the issues is solved , the issue is with the MQTT package, thank you for the support